# Tooltip color changed to System Theme change though Application Requested Theme is different

Tags: xaml, uwp, themes, tooltip, uwp-xaml

I am developing an UWP application. I have theme change option inside my application. When I change theme inside my application, it works good. But when change the system theme to other color, Tooltip of my application is changed. All other controls are working good.

[image]

To change theme inside application I used below code:

```
FrameworkElement root = uIElement != null ? (FrameworkElement)Window.Current.Content : (FrameworkElement)uIElement;

       if (root != null)
        {
            root.RequestedTheme = appMode; // appMode is and ElementTheme
        }
```

I found a solution on internet which suggests to use Tooltip style :

```
<Image.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Background="Black">
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ToolTip>
</Image.ToolTip>
```

But it has a limitation. I can write this style and bind from xaml only. But can't bind from styles.
I have some styles for **button/toggleButton/etc** written in **CommonStyles.xaml**. I wanted to add this custom tooltip style to those styles, but I couldn't. Only I could is to add from  xaml.
As I have too many controls in my application, it is very tough to add "**customToolTip**" style from every control.
Can anyone please help me regarding this??

Update for `Applicaiton.Resources`

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Styles/CommonStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <Color x:Key="ToolTipBG">White</Color>
                    <Color x:Key="ToolTipFG">Black</Color>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <Color x:Key="ToolTipBG">Black</Color>
                    <Color x:Key="ToolTipFG">White</Color>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomToolTipBG" Color="{ThemeResource ToolTipBG}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomToolTipFG" Color="{ThemeResource ToolTipFG}" />
            <StaticResource x:Key="ToolTipBackground" ResourceKey="CustomToolTipBG" />
            <StaticResource x:Key="ToolTipForeground" ResourceKey="CustomToolTipFG" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Still Tooltip changing color for System theme changes.

**Update Screen Capture**

1. Application and System Both in Dark mode:
   [image]
2. Application changes to light mode:
   [image]
3. Application changes to dark mode:
   [image]
4. System changes to light mode:
   [image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to fix the ToolTip background even the theme changed?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT,  Yes, ToolTip background will be aligned to Application Theme, even system theme changes.

Comment: It contains default ToolTip style in the general.xaml file, you could custom it in `Application.Resources` and change the default `ToolTipBackground` ThemeResource as your custom value.

Comment: Any updates for this thread?

Comment: I have commented on your answer, please check.

Comment: Please refer to update part that  define different value for Dark-Light theme inside Application.Resources

Comment: I have updated my post for my current `Applicaiton.Resources`  
Still Tooltip changing color for System theme changes.
Please refer to Update for `Applicaiton.Resources`

Comment: what's mean of `Still Tooltip changing color for System theme changes`?

Comment: if you set the source like the update part, it will follow the system theme to update tooltip theme,  because you used theme resource, and if you want to fix the tooltip theme, please set ToolTipBackground like `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolTipBackground" Color="Red" />`, and it will disable app's theme effect for tooltip.

Comment: And there is no api could meet the requirement that make tooltip not response system theme changing but could response application theme changing. because it is inevitable system theme updating will effect application theme.

Comment: Theme change option is available from application. I want that tooltip will follow this theme only, not the system theme. All other's control are responding fine in this way. Only tooltip have the issue.
You mean, for tooltip there is no way to do this?

Comment: Can you share screen capture to explain  tooltip will follow application but not system?

Comment: I have updated my post "Update Screen Capture"
It is happening only in application runtime. If application closed and launched again, it is fixed. But I require to fix it without application relaunching.
Thanks a lot for your continuous support, please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Ok, I got it, the system theme priority is higher than application's, for tooltip may there is no way to do this. we suggest you set app's theme match with system or set tooltip with single theme.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your kind support :-)

Answer (score 0):

It contains default `ToolTip` style in the `general.xaml` file, you could custom it in `Application.Resources` and change the default ToolTipBackground ThemeResource as your custom value. And if you just want to fix `Background` property, you could also update `ToolTipBackground` StaticResource  separately like the following and place it in `Application.Resources`.

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolTipBackground" Color="Red" />
```

Update

> But I need different value for different theme.

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <!--  Default Theme Dictionary  -->

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <Color x:Key="CustomColor">Red</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <Color x:Key="CustomColor">Green</Color>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomToolTipColor" Color="{ThemeResource CustomColor}" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ToolTipBackground" ResourceKey="CustomToolTipColor" />
```

Comment: I defined "ToolTipBackground" in Dark & Light Theme dictionary.
But when system changed to Light/Dark mode, "ToolTipBackground" is getting value from that dictionary, even though application theme is different.

Comment: Please try to place it into `Application.Resources` directly.

Comment: How will I define different value for Dark-Light theme inside `Application.Resources` ?
It works fine if I use single value for both theme. But I need different value for different theme.

Comment: I have posted an answer above, which is my current `Application.Resources` state. Please check that.